# Updating a table using a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

This is probably very simple but as I am an SQL noobie I do not want to get this wrong and destroy our database.

I am looking at updating a table based on what is in another table. in one table we have a list of users, the form they are in and their tutor. When the form is updated on the front end it does not change the tutor to the one who is related with that form. For example, we have changed the form to the new ones and the tutors below should now read Tom, Dick and Harry respectively:

```
Table 1

   user   |   form   |   tutor
---------------------------------
    a     |  10Tom   |   Bill
    b     |  11Dick  |   Paul
    c     |  9Harry  |   Dave
```

We have another table which links up the respective forms to the correct tutors:

```
Table 2

   form    |   tutor
-----------------------
   10Tom   |   Tom
   11Dick  |   Dick
   9Harry  |   Harry
```

I am thinking the code should look like this, but I do not know if JOIN works in this situation:

```
UPDATE Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.Form = Table2.Form
SET Table1.Tutor = Table2.Tutor
WHERE Table1.Form = Table2.Form
```

Can anyone give me some insight whether this will work? I have backed up the database so hopefully if I do break something I can recover it.

Thanks
Rob

Comment: dbms name please

Comment: dbms is SQL Server 2014

Comment: @CetinBasoz . . . There is no `LEFT JOIN`.  The `WHERE` clause turns it into an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, that is exactly what I mean. You are late into the thread. One of the answers, kept the left join and dropped the WHERE. It was the reason for my comment.

Comment: @GordonLinoff OK removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you can express this as:

```
UPDATE Table1 t1 JOIN
       Table2 t2
       ON t1.Form = t2.Form
    SET t1.Tutor = t2.Tutor;
```

In SQL Server or Postgres, you could do:

```
UPDATE Table1 t1 JOIN
    SET t1.Tutor = t2.Tutor
    FROM Table2 t2
    WHERE t1.Form = t2.Form;
```

In any database, you should be able to do:

```
UPDATE Table1 JOIN
    SET Tutor = (SELECT t2.Tutor
                 FROM Table2 t2
                 WHERE table1.Form = t2.Form
                )
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Table2 t2
                  WHERE table1.Form = t2.Form
                );
```

Answer (score 2):

this should work. I am assuming the requirement needs a left outer join.

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Table1.Tutor = Table2.Tutor
from Table2
where Table1.Form = Table2.Form;
```

Comment: Did you mean "... from Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON ..." ?

Comment: AND are you aware that this is dangerous to execute? It would set the tutor to NULL when there is not a match.

Comment: @CetinBasoz . my bad, i copied his sample and made changes on it, forgot to rewrite the last part. thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the backend you are using but that syntax doesn't look right. Instead do it like:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Table1.Tutor = Table2.Tutor
from table2
WHERE Table1.Form = Table2.Form;
```

Comment: You need to join them

Comment: @Thomas, here inner join is implicit due to where clause:) Zaynal was right you need some tutorials.

Comment: @Thomas is great master for down vote appreciate him for down voting it will help him to make good human :D

Answer (score 1):

```
Update Table1 
SET tutor = t2.tutor
From Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 
on t1.form = t2.form
```